# Prove an entailment is not true via resolution.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Given an entailment $\Sigma ⊨ S$ that I want to prove is false, if I want to prove it with resolution, do I just prove $¬ (\Sigma \implies S)$ instead? If not, how can I do it, still using resolution refutation?

Answer (score 2):

Careful!

$\Sigma$ is a set of statements ... it makes little sense to make that part of a logic statement.

Consider:

$\Sigma = \{ P \}$

$S = Q$

Then $\neg ( \Sigma \Rightarrow S)$ would be $\neg ( \{ P \} \Rightarrow S)$?!?

OK, but I assume that by '$\neg ( \Sigma \Rightarrow S)$' you mean the statement that you obtain by the negating the conditional, whose antecedent is the conjunction of all statements in $\Sigma$, and whose consequent is $S$. So, in this case that would be $\neg(P \Rightarrow Q)$

(BTW: I am assuming that you use the $\Rightarrow$ as the truth-functional operator called the material implication, rather than as the meta-logical symbol for logical implication ... for otherwise $\neg ( \Sigma \Rightarrow S)$ would already make little sense, as it would be trying to use a meta-logical operator inside a logic expression)

OK, but consider. Using the same $\Sigma$ and $S$ as defined:

It is clear that it is not the case that $\{ P \} \vDash Q$, and hence it is not true that $\Sigma \vDash S$

But it is also not the case that $\neg(P \Rightarrow Q)$, and hence it is not true that '$\neg ( \Sigma \Rightarrow S)$'

So no, you can't prove that some logical entailment does not hold by trying to prove the negation of its corresponding conditional.

Comment: So how would I do it, still using resolution refutation?

Comment: @MaxLi Find a counterexample: find a way to make all statements in $\Sigma$ true, but $S$ false.

Comment: Ahhhh how did that not come to mind. Thank you. Are there any other ways if it's hard to make all statements true by hand?

Comment: @MaxLi You're welcome!  Are these propositional logic statements, or first-order logic statements?

Comment: I think it's propositional logic. Oh by the way, I already showed that it's not possible, but my assignment specifically says to use resolution. Is a counterexample really resolution? Thanks again.

Comment: @MaxLi No, not really ... and it's rather unorthodox to use resolution as a demonstration of non-entailment .. Typically, in resolution you negate $S$, add that to the set of statements $\Sigma$, and then derive a contradiction, and then that shows that it is impossible for $S$ to be false while all the statements in $\Sigma$ are true, i.e. that would demonstrate that $S$ *is* entailed by $\Sigma$ .... so to show that $S$ is *not* entailed by $\Sigma$, you'd need to show that it is impossible to derive a contradiction ... so you'd have to show that there are no further resolutions to be done

Comment: @MaxLi To take the example I just used: you'd start with clauses $\{ P \}$ and $\{ \neg Q \}$  ... Well, it's obvious that nothing can be resolved from these ... so the contradiction cannot be resolved ... hence we can conclude that $Q$ is not entailed by $\{ P \}$. ... of course, that last inference we can only make if we know that the resolution method is complete (i.e. that for *all* entailmentss it can derive the contradiction from the corresponding clauses) ... but for propositional logic as well as first-order logic it is.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $\Sigma\vDash S$ by resolution, show that the CNF clausal form of $\Sigma\cup\{ \neg S\}$ can be resolved down to emptiness (ie, that the union cannot be satisfied).

Eg:  $p, p\to (q\vee r), r\to q\vDash q$ is proven by resolving $$\{(p), (\neg p,q,r),(\neg r,q),(\neg q)\}\\\{(q,r),(\neg r,q),(\neg q)\}\\\{(q),(\neg q)\}\\\{\}$$

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. I want to prove that the entailment does not hold.

Comment: That will be difficult, since it actually does hold.